# R - Merge all JSONs in a file

Tags: r, json, dataframe, merge

I want to combine all files in a folder in one DataFrame. All the files are identically structured. An example:

```
{"title": "Olijvenpest duikt op", "source": "De Standaard", "source_page": "18", "date": "2018-10-16", "body": "In een tuincentrum in Roeselare werd eind september op olijfbomen voor het eerst een dodelijke bacterie gevonden"}
```

R is able to see all the files with the following code:

```
library(jsonlite)
path <- "..."
files <- dir(path, pattern = "*",full.names = TRUE)
```

However, I'm unable to combine all the files. I have tried numerous options discussed on stackoverflow, but they always result in errors.

Each json should be one observation with the different variables: title, source, date,...

Kind regards
Steven

Answer (score 0):

Import all these files in a vector:

```
x <- character(length(files))
for(i in seq_along(files)){
  x[i] <- readLines(files[i])
}
```

Create the JSON representation of the dataframe:

```
json <- paste0("[", paste0(x, collapse = ","), "]")
```

Now use 'jsonlite': `fromJSON(json)`.

Comment: I got the following error after trying your first code:
"Error in x[i] <- readLines(files[i]) : replacement has length zero
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)"

Comment: @StevenUA Perhaps this error is due to an empty file. For the warnings, my guess is that the files have more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

First, you read in the JSON files with

```
files <- dir(pattern = "*.json", full.names = TRUE)
JSON <- lapply(files, function(z) rjson::fromJSON(file = z))
```

Note that you need to have your `.json` files in an appropriate folder for this to work where the folder is also your current working directory.

Then you transform your read-in files with the help of tidyverse's dplyr like so

```
JSON_New <- lapply(JSON, function(x) {cols <- names(x); x %>% 
  unique %>% 
  unlist %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("Content") %>% 
  mutate(Category = names(x)) %>%  
  select(3, 2)})
```

so that you receive a list of data.frames that you can now rename according to your filename with

```
names(myJSON_New) <- files
```

For example, if I use your given example file twice then I'll get the following output after I followed the steps that I described up til now.

```
[[1]]
     Category                                                                                                                .
1       title                                                                                             Olijvenpest duikt op
2      source                                                                                                     De Standaard
3 source_page                                                                                                               18
4        date                                                                                                       2018-10-16
5        body In een tuincentrum in Roeselare werd eind september op olijfbomen voor het eerst een dodelijke bacterie gevonden

[[2]]
     Category                                                                                                                .
1       title                                                                                             Olijvenpest duikt op
2      source                                                                                                     De Standaard
3 source_page                                                                                                               18
4        date                                                                                                       2018-10-16
5        body In een tuincentrum in Roeselare werd eind september op olijfbomen voor het eerst een dodelijke bacterie gevonden
```

Then, to combine the list of data.frames such that one json is one row you can do

```
> A <- JSON_New %>% reduce(inner_join, by = "Category") %>% data.table::transpose(.)
                    V1           V2          V3         V4                                                                                                               V5
1                title       source source_page       date                                                                                                             body
2 Olijvenpest duikt op De Standaard          18 2018-10-16 In een tuincentrum in Roeselare werd eind september op olijfbomen voor het eerst een dodelijke bacterie gevonden
3 Olijvenpest duikt op De Standaard          18 2018-10-16 In een tuincentrum in Roeselare werd eind september op olijfbomen voor het eerst een dodelijke bacterie gevonden
```